# How to print the table from a website using python script?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my python script so far.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'my_company_website'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"navigator-content"})

print (containers)
```

After this, in inspect element it is like below,

```
<div class ="issue-table-container">
<div>
<table id ="issuetable" class>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>...<t/body> (This contains all the information i want to print)
</table>
```

How to print the table and export to csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the containers you should grab the table [1], then you have to find the body of the table and iterate over its rows [2] and compile a line for your csv file with the table cells (td) [3]

```
for container in containers:
    table = container.find(id="issuetable") [1]
    #if you are exactly sure of the structure and/or if the tables have different/unique ids and there is only one table per container you can also do:
    table = container.table [1]

    for tr in table.tbody.find_all("tr"): [2]
        line = ""
        for td in tr: [3]
            line += td.text+"," #Adding the text in the td to the line followed by the separator of your choice in this case comma
        csvfile.write(line[:-1]+"/n") #add the line (replace "/n" with your system's new line character for extra portability)
```

There are different ways of navigating the soup tree depending on your need and on how flexible you script needs to be.
Have a look at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ and check out the find / find_all sections.

Good luck!

/Teo